# Loading Matlab matrix into Labview array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, gps, labview

I have a matrix which contains GPS waypoints (4 columns - lat,long,h,time) and I would like to use this in a Labview programme to control a UAV.

The code I am working from has a waypoint array to input the waypoints manually from the front panel, but I would like to load this set of points.

I have never used Labview before, so I am having trouble modifying the programme.

Thanks!

Comment: You can save the matrix in csv format, and in Labview Block Diagram use FileIO>Read from spreadsheet file

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it helped you, or maybe provide your own answer.

Comment: Not sure if you're still around, but if you are and the answer provided helped, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on a comment, one way that you could do this is to save your MATLAB matrix in a format that you can easily read in LabVIEW, for instance CSV. In MATLAB, [save your matrix to a CSV file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html):

```matlab
csvwrite(filename, mymat)
```

where `filename` is whatever you want it to be surrounded by quotes, e.g. `'GPS_data.csv'`, and `mymat` is your data. Then in LabVIEW you can read the contents of the file into a 2D array using `Read From Spreadsheet File.vi`. Each row of the resulting 2D matrix will a single waypoint, and you can process that data however you see fit. An example that does nothing but display each row after a short delay is shown below.

[image: Example VI]

You could hard-code the filename that you want to read into the `Read From Spreadsheet File.vi`, or execute your VI without anything wired in to be prompted for a CSV file to read.